# Dump django debug output to a file?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I noticed in the django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins) that when DEBUG is False it will mail your configured ADMINS the full exception information.

Is there an easy way to dump the full exception information this to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can [find](http://www.djangosnippets.org/) or [write middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) to catch it.

Comment: Thanks, ended up creating a simple middleware class to handle the 'process_exception' method.